# Max number of flags on highstock control

Tags: highcharts

It seems that when number of flags exceeds 1000, flags are not displayed on control.
Is it a bug or this behavior can be changed somehow?

See jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/SDknv/

When ran as is, this code will not show any flags on series.
If you change line `var flagsCount = 1001` to `var flagsCount = 1000` and run example again, all 1000 flags will be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should increase turboThreshold parameter: http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.turboThreshold